# How to spot plagiarized logos?

Tags: google, design, images, image-search

Is there a better method of finding if a logo is a shameless copy of another logo, other than Google's image search tool?

Answer (score 7):

You could try [Tin Eye](http://www.tineye.com)

You either upload your file or give it an address and it:

> ... finds out where an image came from, how it is being used, if modified versions of the image exist, or if there is a higher resolution version.

[Source](http://www.tineye.com/about)